# Getting Optimum Router and LinkSys Smart Wi-Fi to play nice?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router

My mother has a "whacked out" setup that's partly a legacy setup from before my father died. Neither of us know exactly what's going on with the legacy stuff, except that there's home-control (lights, etc.) on the Linksys network. When all this was set up, the LinkSys was the only router around, connected to DSL.

The main internet for computers, however, is now cable service from Optimum, due to Verizon no longer supporting their copper network and trying to force their copper customers to FIOS - which doesn't support third-party DSL. Right now, the physical setup is

Internet -> Optimum modem -> Optimum Router WAN port|Optimum router LAN port -> LinkSys Smart Wifi master node

The Optimum router is also Wi-Fi, and the computers normally connect to Optimum, not LinkSys.

The LinkSys Smart Wifi has two devices, one in the basement near the Optimum modem, one upstairs. They're not wired together; they're wireless-to-wireless, and are access points for the same network/subnet - that is, I can have one computer downstairs talking to the basement node, and one upstairs talking to the bedroom node, and they're on the same subnet and can share files and printers.

The Optimum subnet is 192.168.1.0/24; the LinkSys subnet is 10.227.1.0/24

Most of the time, everything is fine. Occasionally, though, something gets massively confused, and one of the computers ends up with an Optimum IPv4 address, but the default gateway and DNS server are somehow set to the values that the LinkSys would issue if I connected to the LinkSys. When that happens, I lose internet connectivity, and the only way I seem to be able to "unconfuse" things is to disconnect the LinkSys, reboot the Optimum router, and on the computer, do `IPCONFIG/RELEASE`, `IPCONFIG/FLUSHDNS`, and `IPCONFIG/RENEW` after the Optimum router comes back up. Then, I can reconnect the LinkSys, and all will be OK - for a while; eventually, I'll have to go through this again. Mom's not technically savvy, though, and while I've simplified the IPCONFIG stuff for her for the occasions where that will work without resetting routers and modems, I can't rely on her to be able to do the router/modem resets.

Unfortunately, the Smart Wifi doesn't seem to have the same level of control (management) that the Cisco/LinkSys WRT or WAP series devices do, and the Optimum router can't be managed at all if I don't have connectivity through it to the Internet.

1. How can I find out exactly what devices are involved in the home-control setup? There are some light controls and a Nest, and two apps on Mom's iPhone (Lutron is one; the other may be for the Nest), but I don't know what else if anything, and I don't know how to reconfigure things - my father left everything undocumented because he had no plans on dying, didn't think much of my mother's intelligence, and he and I weren't talking due to a temper tantrum he threw well over 20 years ago.
2. How can I re-set the wi-fi channels of the Optimum, the LinkSys, or both, to ensure that they're not both on the same channel? I suspect that the confusion might be due to them interfering with each other, but I don't know for sure, and I can't see anything in the "management" screens for either that would tell me what channels they're on.
3. How can I prevent the confusion outlined above, where I have an Optimum IP but a LinkSys gateway? Ideally, I'd also like the LinkSys to simply pass all internet traffic right to the Optimum router - about the same type of setup that I have on my own home network, but I'm not using a Smart Wifi.